# Symfony2: Clearing frontend cache in code

Tags: symfony, caching, internationalization

I'm building an application in which translation strings are loaded from `messages.en.yml` and parsed into an editable form for the user. When the form is submitted it will write all the data to `messages.en.yml`, this way the user has full control over `i18n` strings.

This is working like a charm in `dev` environment, but in `prod` the `.yml` file is cached. I'd like to clear the frontend/config cache when changes are made so that changes are visible.

Believe it or not, but Google does not give any viable results as to how to clear the cache programmatically. I don't want to delete all of the cache, as doing this will log the user out. Any clues?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't load the data from the yml in the first place, I'd use a database or other dynamic store for that. Or you could maybe look at running http://uk3.php.net/shell_exec to run cache:clear --env=prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the prettiest solution, but this is what I've used to bust my cache. Calling this after writing the new contents to the file using the `Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper`:

```
// Bust cache
$fs->remove(sprintf('%s/translations/catalogue.%s.php', $this->kernel->getCacheDir(), $this->getLocale()));
```